# How to include font-awesome when typing b4 in Visual Code HTML?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have installed bootstrap plug-in and normally use the quick link b4 to have all my needed (including font-awesome) installed.
However, today my fontawesome is not working. Turn out that the  tag to fontawesome is not appear automatically anymore?
How do I configure my Visual Code to reappear that feature, and more important, how to stop   my compiler to remove feature without my consent?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. For future programmers, you should remember to include font-awesome cdn first.

Comment: ouh, I ddin't know vscode can auto complete from cdn.